# How likely is it that a lawyer will know the skilled practitioners in their area who practice in a different area?

Tags: united-states, bar-association

I would like to find the best criminal attorney in my area, which is an area where the biggest towns have about 50,000 people. I know a very prominent attorney who has practiced for a long time and is active in the state bar association, however, he is a personal injury attorney, not criminal. How likely is it that he will be a keen judge of the best criminal attorneys in the area?

I have asked a range of people for advice of the best criminal attorney in the area and gotten different answers.

Comment: I would expect different answers from different people.

Comment: I would expect there to be overlap in a top-5 list.

Comment: I would expect lawyers (of any type) would have some idea of who is good in an area - certainly a (very competent but small-time) property lawyer I happened to know socially knew who was sharp and where to turn in the legal fraternity.   As he will have a "legal mindset" and bar membership, he is better placed then the average person to get relevant information and make appropriate judgements.   As others have said though, there is likely no single best lawyer, but a small handful of really good ones.

Comment: Also, if you are looking out for well vetted ones, and it applies in your jurisdiction - Look for lawyers who are  "Queens Council" (QC).   I might also be inclined to go down to the local court and have a chat with the registrar - you would want to be careful exactly what you ask, as they generally cannot advise a certain lawyer, but there may be nothing to stop you asking if there is a list of judgements in the area of interest which includes the representing lawyers.

Comment: Depends on the court in question. Some townships have like 3 lawyers and the judge and all are hunting buddies, others are New York where you have enough agents of the court to populate a whole town.

Comment: It depends what is meant by the subjective use of "best". Do they win cases because they're experienced experts in their chosen field, do they only take on sure-fire wins, or do they take on the most challenging cases with no guarantees in order to give their client the opportunity to seek redress?

Answer (score 1):

" a very prominent attorney who has practiced for a long time and is active in the state bar association" is likely to know many lawyers in the area by reputation, and quite a few personally, and have a fair idea of who has a good reputation in a particular area. Such a person might well know who to ask to get more detailed information than s/he knows personally.

Also, many states and localities in the US have legal referral services run by the bar association or some other non-commercial group. These will not indicate who is the "best" but should provide a listing of competent lawyers in active practice in a given field or sub-field of law.

Comment: Yes, I already have the competent list. In fact, I already have one of them. I need a better one. I need better than competent.